# Is this a good case for use of RoutedCommand?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, routed-commands

I have a WPF page that has 2 ContentControls on it.  Both of the ContentControls have an image, one being much smaller than the other.  When mouse over the larger image I want to show a zoomed in view on the smaller image.  Something very similar to this: http://www.trekbikes.com/us/en/bikes/urban/soho/soho/.

I think I want the larger image control to send out something that actually contains an image - which the smaller image control would pick up and display.  Would this be a good place to take advantage of RoutedCommands?  Can I pass along an image like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RoutedCommands seem a bit misplaced in this case...  you'll want the mouse to respond smoothly and the last thing you want are commands to be fired off here and there.

You're probably better off using a VisualBrush.  While Ian Griffith's example [here](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2005/05/29/magnify) is a magnifying glass (an early canonical VisualBrush example in WPF) you could easily adapt it to show a portion of your image.

Comment: That isn't exactly what I ended up doing, but your answer started me down a path that led to my final solution.